# Error de código C, poner puntos delante de las palabras en un fichero .txt

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer una función que ponga 3 puntos delante de cada dos palabras del fichero .txt que le abro, he hecho la función y luego la llamo en un switch, pero no me funciona y no veo donde puede estar el error.

```
void frase_lenta1 (char frase[MAX_F][MAX_C], char frase2[MAX_F][MAX_C]){

    char caracter;
    int i, j, cont_p, n;
    FILE*fit;
    n= cont_p % 2;
    cont_p=0;
    for(i=0; i < MAX_F; i++)
    {
        fit = fopen(frase, "r");
        for(j=0; j<MAX_C; j++){
            while(frase[i][j]!= '.' && frase[i][j]!= '\0'){
                if(frase[i][j]==' '){
                    cont_p++;
                }
                if(n == 0){
                    frase2[i][j]= frase[i][j];
                    frase2[i][j] = '.';
                    frase2[i][j+1] = '.';
                    frase2[i][j+2]= '.';
                }
            }
        }

    while((caracter = fgetc(fit)) != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c", caracter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Abre el fichero una vez al inicio de la función, acuerdate de cerrarlo. Al hacer fopen(frase, "r") se te va a abrir siempre desde el principio.

Comment: ¿Por qué `cont_p` no está inicializado antes de usarse? ¿Qué entrada esperas tener y qué salida esperas ver?

Comment: la entrada que espero tener es la del fichero y la salida el fichero modificado

Comment: Genial. ¿No puedes poner un ejemplo de entrada que esperas tener y la salida que esperas obtener?

Comment: Yo he creado la función de arriba  , y luego tengo un switch para llamar a la función, y lo que quiero que haga es que del fichero que lee, ponga 3 puntos cada dos palabras

Comment: Chachi. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de la entrada que esperas procesar y cómo quedará esa entrada después de haber sido procesada?

Comment: abre el fichero, y por ejemplo hay 3 frases en 3 linias, cada frase terminada con un. 
hola que tal.
adios muy bien.
estoy muy bien.

y lo que quiero que salga seria esto
hola que ...tal.
adios muy ...bien.
estoy muy ...bien.

Comment: Si quieres procesar de un archivo ¿Por qué la función `frase_lenta1` recibe datos desde fuera?

Comment: porque fuera tengo un printf que te dice que pongas el nombre del archivo i un gets(frase)

Comment: Eso que dices no tiene ningún sentido. La función `frase_lenta1` recibe dos formaciones con texto, no recibe una sola cadena de texto como nombre del archivo. ¿Seguro que entiendes tu código?

Comment: ¿y como puedo hacer esto entonces?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer? El código que muestras es completamente ajeno al objetivo que tienes.